# Different Layout in Xcode Preview and Real Device

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am a beginner in Swift UI, I recently started learning it and was working on a personal beginner project. So the issue is, the contents seem to be center aligned in the xcode preview, and that is how i want it. But when I run the application in my iphone or on a simulator, the contents mode their places. I am not sure why is this happening.

As you can see in the screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftVD6.jpg)

I think it worked fine before I implemented the background image. But I am not really sure when it started to do like that.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you debug this issue without any actual code to reproduce the issue. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do verify you've set vertically and horizontally constraints right. Because the reason behind this issue is that subviews aren't aligned properly.
Show me the code if possible.

Comment: That worked. I was using gemoetry reader to embed my view codes. I changed it and updated other constraints. That worked. Thankyou. Happy coding